# How to update Nuget tools-only packages via command line

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Is it possible to update a "tools-only" Nuget package via the command line?

By "tools-only", I mean a package that does not contain a "lib" or "content" folder (according to the definition on the Nuget site), and contains scripts or tools rather than libraries that are referenced by Visual Studio Projects. A typical use is for tools that assist with build processes.

I am able to add tools-only packages in Visual Studio by managing the Nuget packages at the Solution level. That will download the package correctly, and also let me see and install updates to it.

But I've not been able to get the "update" command of the "nuget.exe" command line app to do the package update. It appears to drive all updates from the project files... but the package is not referenced by a project because it's not a code library.

I understand the focus of Nuget is code libraries, but the doco does make mention of tools packages... Given that it can be done within Visual Studio, I'd have thought the same should be possible on the command line.

E.g.

- Tool package "A" (no lib, just tools folder)
- In VS in project "B", manage Nuget packages on solution and install A
- (Will download, and create ".nuget" folder with packages.config)
- Release new version of "A"

In this scenario, I can see and install the update within VS, but cannot get the right command line to install the update.